# dificultades con ng-click y mostrar datos con AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo una app que muestra las personas registradas para un evento y su lugar correspondiente.

Codigo en jade. A grandes rasgos es una lista que muestra el nombre de la persona, en que mesa esta ubicado y cuantos invitados tienen

```
  div.centralCont-column 
          h2.centralCont--titulo INVITADOS
          ul.centralCont--list 
            li(ng-repeat="mesa in mesas")
              div(ng-repeat="nombre in mesa.integrantes |  filter:buscar").centralCont-invitado
                div.centralCont-contNombre(ng-hide="nombre.nombre === 'Acompañante'")
                  div.centralCont-nombres 
                    div.aling-left
                      input(type="checkbox" ng-model="nombre.done" ng-click="onMark($event)").checkbox
                      h3.centrarCont--invtNombre(ng-click="mostrar()") {{nombre.nombre}}
                  button(type="button" ng-show="!mesa.visible" ng-click="mesa.visible = true") Mostrar
                button(type="button" ng-show="mesa.visible" ng-click="mesa.visible = true") Ocultar
                  div.central-cont-mesa
                    p.central-cont--mesa {{nombre.mesa}}
                    p.centralCont--entrada Mesa
```

Lo que no he podido hacer es que si le doy click a un invitado que esta en la mesa 1 me muestre todos los invitados de la mesa 1 en otro div (solo los nombres) y si despues doy click en un invitado que esta en la mesa dos oculte los invitados de la mesa 1 y muestre los invitados de la mesa dos

en js tengo varias cosas.

```
$scope.mesas = [{
      "mesa": "mesa1",
      "integrantes": [{
        "nombre": "Susana Sofia Urrea Sotelo",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }, {
        "nombre": "Alan Meyer Zaragoza",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Karla Irene Urrea Sotelo",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Marcus",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Nelly Ponce Sotelo",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Acompañante",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Grecia Magdalena Sotelo Lara",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Celso",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Paulina Sotelo Medina",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }, {
        "nombre": "Acompañante",
        "mesa": "1",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }],
    },{
      "mesa": "mesa2",
      "integrantes": [{
        "nombre": "Ivan Ponce Sotelo",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }, {
        "nombre": "Karla Sandoval",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Jorge Echeagaray Sotelo",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Jose Arturo Otero Davila",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Humberto Jimenez Arellano",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "David Aceves",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Arturo Fernando Lomeli Sotelo",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Zaira",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      },{
        "nombre": "Scarlete Sanchez Sotelo",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }, {
        "nombre" : "luis",
        "mesa": "2",
        "entradas": "1",
        "usadas": "0,",
        "done" : false,
      }]
    }],
```

}];

y un codigo que me hace un checking

```
"use stric";

var app = angular.module("app", ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller("MesasCtrl", ($scope) =>{
  $scope.people = 0;
  $scope.markedPeople = 0;
  (() => {
    $scope.mesas.forEach(table => {
      table.integrantes.forEach(member => {
        if(member.nombre !== 'Acompañante' && member.nombre) {
          $scope.people++;
        }
      });
    });
  })();

  $scope.onMark = (ev) => {
    if(ev.target.checked) {
      $scope.markedPeople++;
    } else {
      $scope.markedPeople--;
    }
  }
});
```

Donde quiero que aparezcas los nombres es esta parte de la vista

```
div.centralCont-column 
  h2.centralCont--titulo INFORMACIÓN DE LA MESA
  div.centralCont-invitado
    div(ng-repeat="mesa in mesas") 
      div(ng-show="mesa.visible")
        p(ng-repeat="nombre in mesa.integrantes", ng-class="{'done-true':nombre.done}").centralCont-invitado__text {{nombre.nombre}}
```

Comment: Creo entender que sucede, pero si no muestras el código javascript/angular muy difícil va a ser saber donde esta el problema.

Comment: listo, actualice la pregunta

Comment: Ya vi, sabes como indexar el código de tal forma en la pregunta para que pueda ejecutarse?

Comment: no, como hago eso??

Comment: Bueno amigo creo saber cual puede ser el error, se supone que para seleccionar los de una mesa al darle click a un nombre, debes enviar un parámetro, en este caso el numero de la mesa, `ng-click="mostrar()"` no estas enviando ningún parámetro, prueba eso, de igual forma, voy a tratar de resolverlo

Comment: el mostrar lo hago con los botones que estan ahi, pero tengo que precionar mostrar y luego ocultar para poder presionar otro boton de otra mesa y mostrar su contenido, lo que quiero es hacerlo todos esos procesos al presionar los nombres

Answer (score 1):

yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
$scope.listaMesas= [] //Esta es mi lista de invitados
$scope.showMesa= [] // los invitados a mostrar
var mesa = -2;

// Con esta funcion seteo los invitados de la mesa y si ya estan mostrandose los oculto
$scope.setShowInvitados = function(key){
  $scope.showInvitados = (mesa == key) ? $scope.listaMesas[key] : [];
}
```